# How can I completely remove files of Anaconda as it is not installing properly?

Tags: python, anaconda

I tried to install Anaconda3-4.1.1-Linux-x86_64.sh, but after saving files in terminal an error comes saying permission denied. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Where are you trying to install? Anaconda does not needs root privileges to install, it needs only  a user writable location. Try installing to `~/anaconda`. After extraction, just add the location to the **PATH**.

Comment: The last paragraph of the accepted answer to the linked duplicate question has the instructions for completely removing Anaconda files.

Answer (score 7):

### Downloading and Installing Anaconda (Linux)

1. Download Anaconda from https://www.continuum.io/downloads.
2. Run installer script:

   `$ bash AnacondaX-x.x.x-Linux-x86[_64].sh`
3. Accept the license (<kbd>enter</kbd> shows the license). After reading it, scroll to the end with <kbd>space</kbd>. Accept it by typing `yes` and <kbd>enter</kbd> when required.
4. Specify the install location. (Default is `~/anacondaX`, where X is the major version of Python release, e.g. X=3 for Python 3.5)
5. Add this location to **PATH** if your installer asks you to. Otherwise, you should add this location on your own to you PATH in `~/.bashrc`:

   `export PATH="/home/$USER/anacondaX/bin:$PATH"`

### Uninstalling

Anaconda is installed in a single directory. So, for uninstalling it, just remove the entire directory. Default install location is `~/anacondaX`. Removing is easy:

```
rm -rf ~/anacondaX
```

Comment: great.  thanks.  this removed error preventing me from using c++ opencv.  hope it helps someone else remove anaconda! I did not need to edit my .bashrc file... error was getting was ~/anaconda3/lib/libicui18n.so.58: undefined reference to `__cxa_throw_bad_array_new_length@CXXABI_1.3.8'